# How do i automatically set a date based on data entered from Google form?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there a way to automatically set a date based on data entered from form?

Tried the below, but when the data enters the sheet, the new date isnt populated except if i manually edit it.

I tried onChange, same result.

```
 function onEdit(e){

 addTimeStamp(e);

}

function addTimeStamp(e){

//Variables

var startRow = 2; 

var targetColumn = 3;

var ws = "Form Responses 1";

//Get modified row and column

var row = e.range.getRow();

var col = e.range.getColumn();


if(col === targetColumn && row >= startRow && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === ws){

var currentDate = new Date();

e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,7).setValue(currentDate);

if(e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,6).getValue() ==""){

e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,6).setValue(currentDate);

}// End IF - Check if Date created exists

}//End IF - Check column,row & worksheet

}//End Function AddTimeStamp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The onEdit() trigger does not fire when a form submits data to a linked sheet.  It only fires for user edits.  But you may be able to perform the same function from the onFormSubmit Trigger.

[simple triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#getting_started)

This is what the event object contains:

```
{"authMode":"","namedValues":{"Timestamp":["5/23/2021 19:53:03"],"COL1":["","2"],"Email Address":[""],"COL2":["","1"],"COL3":["","My answer"]},"range":{"columnEnd":8,"columnStart":1,"rowEnd":21,"rowStart":21},"source":{},"triggerUid":"","values":["5/23/2021 19:53:03","","","","","2","1","My answer",""]}
```

So you have access to range, range.columnStart, range.columnEnd and range.rowStart and range.rowEnd are always the same because it submits one row at a time.  So you will have to readjustment some of the values in your current function.

So I believe this would be your new timestamp function():

```
function addTimeStamp(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(e.range.getSheet() == 'Form Responses 1') {//this will differentiate between different form submissions to the same spreadsheet
    const dt = new Date();
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 7).setValue(dt);
    if (sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 6).getValue() == "") {
      sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 6).setValue(dt);
    }
  }
}
```

This code was designed to run on the onFormSubmit trigger not the onEdit trigger.  Please note as I described about that the edit performed by a form submission does not create an onedit trigger.  You can only create an onedit trigger with a user edit.

#### Edit:

You should install [this trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/spreadsheet-trigger-builder#onFormSubmit()) for this to work (see [installable triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) and form submit [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit)).

Comment: Thanks @Cooper, can i run the code as is, or use onEdit?

Thank you.

Comment: You cannot run it  from the script editor without providing the event object.  And this code was designed to run on the onFormSubmit trigger not the onEdit.  As I pointed out in the answer that the edit that is performed by  the form submission does not trigger an onEdit trigger.

Comment: Thanks again @ Cooper, i tried the above code, and set the trigger as addTimeStamp(e) but i dont get any value on the sheet.

Perhaps i am doing something wrong.

Comment: You will have to submit the appropriate form to get it to work.

Comment: Thanks alot. I have tried a few times but cant seem to get the auto timestamp to populate. 

In my script, i only used your answer and added the trigger under add trigger functions.

I am not sure if i need to declare any other variables apart from your code.

Comment: @KingMichaelKing You have to install the onFormSubmit trigger. See the edited part of this answer for more info.